# Executing a SQL Server stored procedure in R but not getting the CSV files

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I am trying to execute a SQL Server stored procedure in R. The result of the SQL Server procedure is supposed to be used in the rest of the R code. Typically, the result of the SQL Server procedure is a few CSV files that are saved in a specified folder.

In the R code, I would like to either:

1. generate those CSV files on the specified folder that I can import them later in R again

or

2. have the contents of the CSV files as a few tables (matrix or data frame) in R without saving them anywhere.

In order to connect to the SQL Server and execute the stored procedure, I wrote the following code:

```
library(RODBC)

querystring <- paste("DECLARE @return_value int,",
                 "@Status int ",
                 "exec @return_value = pEDC_RunStandalone @SourceDB = 
mySourceDB,",
                 "@PortInfoID = 'ALL',",
                 "@DestFileFolder = mySpecifiedDestinationPath,",
                 "@ConvertEQAsEQFire = 1,", 
                 "@Status = @Status OUTPUT ",
                 "SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value",
                 sep ="")

conn<- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=myServer;database=myDatabaseName;trusted_connection=no;uid=myUID;pwd=myPassword')

data <- sqlQuery(conn,querystring, errors=FALSE)

odbcCloseAll()
```

The code works with no ERROR or WARNINGS. So, I think it can connect to the server with no issue and it should be able to run the stored procedure. However, the CSV files are not generated!

I copy/paste the querystring in a sql query file and ran it in SQL Server Management Studio and it worked and generated the CSV result files.

Any idea that what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Sorry that I cannot make any reproducible code more than what I provided above!

Comment: I've run some tests on your problem. Created a Stored proc which is outputing a file and called it from R. I have no issues on SQL Server 2016. One point to note is that if you have multiple output in your Stored procedure, only the first one will be returned to R, therefore this could mask your issues, like wrong path etc. Can you specify how you are creating your CSV files?

Comment: Hi Arnaud, 
thanks for your interest and participation.
The stored proc is supposed to export more than one csv files, so we have more than one output. However, we do not get even one.

The stored proc actually calls a CLR stored proc. "WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS EXTERNAL NAME [server]..[pClrExportToFile]"

Comment: I would check the security of the user which is running the R processes. There may be restriction on execution of CLR that you would not have when you execute the stored procedure yourself. check the rights of the the SQLRUserGroup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/add-sqlrusergroup-to-database?view=sql-server-2017